# How do you split a XmlNodeList into two sub-XmlNodeList?

Tags: c#, xmlnodelist

How can I split a XmlNodeList into two smaller XmlNodeList, where one have size N, and the other have size total - N?

See below for an example and where I was trying to go with this:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument someDoc = new XmlDocument();
        someDoc.LoadXml(@"<bananas>
                            <banana tasty='yes'></banana>
                            <banana tasty='very'></banana>
                            <banana tasty='amazing'></banana>
                            <banana tasty='mind-blowing'></banana>
                            <banana tasty='disgusting'></banana>
                          </bananas>");
        XmlNodeList bananaNodeList = someDoc.SelectNodes("//banana");
        eatSomeBananas(bananaNodeList, 2);
    }

    /** Splits a XmlNodeList into two XmlNodeList, first one is a slice from 0 to numberOfBananas-1, and the other slice is from numberOfBananas and onwards
    */
    public static void eatSomeBananas(XmlNodeList subBananaNodeList, int numberOfBananas)
    {
        XmlNodeList bananasToEat = subBananaNodeList.Cast<XmlNode>().Take(numberOfBananas) as XmlNodeList; //Error down-casting - null!
        if (bananasToEat == null)
            Console.WriteLine("Error! Did not work");
        /*else 
            doSomethingHere(bananasToEat); */
        XmlNodeList remainingBananas = subBananaNodeList.Cast<XmlNode>().Skip(numberOfBananas) as XmlNodeList; //Error down-casting - null!
        eatSomeBananas(remainingBananas, numberOfBananas);
    }
```

I tried to cast a `XmlNodeList` to a `IEnumerable<XmlNode>` (since the former inherits from the latter) - I believe this should be an upcast. Shouldn't I be able downcast this back into a `XmlNodeList` afterwards? But if not, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't I be able downcast this back into a XmlNodeList afterwards? But if not, why not?

No, because the value returned from `Skip` isn't an `XmlNodeList`. It's only declared to be an `IEnumerable<XmlNode>`, and I'd expect the `Skip` implementation to probably use an iterator block... certainly I'd be surprised if `Skip` had any detailed knowledge of `XmlNodeList`. `Take` would work in exactly the same way.

Personally I'd avoid using the old XML API at all, and just use LINQ to XML. That plays naturally with LINQ - and is generally a nicer XML API, IMO.

You don't *have* to use that, mind you - you could just change the whole of your code to use `IEnumerable<XmlNode>` instead of `XmlNodeList`:

```
public static void eatSomeBananas(IEnumerable<XmlNode> subBananaNodeList, int numberOfBananas)
{
    IEnumerable<XmlNode> bananasToEat = subBananaNodeList.Take(numberOfBananas);
    IEnumerable<XmlNode> remainingBananas = subBananaNodeList.Skip(numberOfBananas);
    // Added condition to avoid infinite recursion
    if (remainingBananas.Any())
    {
        eatSomeBananas(remainingBananas, numberOfBananas);
    }
}
```

Then you can just call `Cast` once when you call the method:

```
eatSomeBananas(bananaNodeList.Cast<XmlNode>(), 2);
```

Here's the LINQ to XML version though, which I prefer:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument someDoc = XDocument.Parse(
            @"<bananas>
                <banana tasty='yes'></banana>
                <banana tasty='very'></banana>
                <banana tasty='amazing'></banana>
                <banana tasty='mind-blowing'></banana>
                <banana tasty='disgusting'></banana>
              </bananas>");
        IEnumerable<XElement> bananas = someDoc.Descendants("banana");
        EatSomeBananas(bananas, 2);
    }

    public static void EatSomeBananas(IEnumerable<XElement> bananas, int numberOfBananas)
    {
        var bananasToEat = bananas.Take(numberOfBananas);
        Console.WriteLine("Eating some bananas"); 
        foreach (var element in bananasToEat)
        {
            var tasty = element.Attribute("tasty").Value;
            Console.WriteLine($"Tasty: {tasty}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Eaten the bananas");
        var remainingBananas = bananas.Skip(numberOfBananas);
        if (remainingBananas.Any())
        {
            EatSomeBananas(remainingBananas, numberOfBananas);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that for a production implementation, I'd avoid the recursion and potentially materialize the result periodically - otherwise it'll be iterating from the start every time, skipping a load and then taking some.

Comment: Thank you Daisy, could you also expand on how to materialize the result a little? I didn’t quite follow that part

Comment: @WCGPR0: Well you *could* call `ToList()`, e.g. `IEnumerable<XmlNode> remainingBananas = subBananaNodeList.Skip(numberOfBananas).ToList();` That would be wasteful in other ways though. Basically I'd try to avoid this recursion, but without knowing what you're trying to do in more detail it's hard to propose a concrete alternative.

Comment: I had the same answer as Daisy (using IEnumerable<XmlNode>), but I was a half hour too slow.
Also, as Daisy says, I would also encourage you to use the XDocument et al classes instead of the XmlDocument stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I just converted to an IQueryable and used that, much easier to work with than the XmlNodeList.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument someDoc = new XmlDocument();
        someDoc.LoadXml(@"<bananas>
                        <banana tasty='yes'></banana>
                        <banana tasty='very'></banana>
                        <banana tasty='amazing'></banana>
                        <banana tasty='mind-blowing'></banana>
                        <banana tasty='disgusting'></banana>
                      </bananas>");
        XmlNodeList bananaNodeList = someDoc.SelectNodes("//banana");

        var allBananas = bananaNodeList.Cast<XmlNode>().AsQueryable();

        eatSomeBananas(allBananas, 2);
    }

    public static void eatSomeBananas(IQueryable<XmlNode> subBananas, int numberOfBananas)
    {
        var bananasToEat = subBananas.Take(numberOfBananas);
        var remainingBananas = subBananas.Skip(numberOfBananas);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Bananas to eat: {0}", bananasToEat.Count()));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Remaining bananas: {0}", remainingBananas.Count()));
        if (!bananasToEat.Any())
            Console.WriteLine("Error! Did not work (not enough bananas!)");
        else 
            eatSomeBananas(remainingBananas, numberOfBananas);
    }
```

Output:

```
Bananas to eat: 2
Remaining bananas: 3
Bananas to eat: 2
Remaining bananas: 1
Bananas to eat: 1
Remaining bananas: 0
Bananas to eat: 0
Remaining bananas: 0
Error! Did not work (not enough bananas!)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `IQueryable<T>` at all, or query expressions. Why not just use `IEnumerable<T>`, and just `subBananas.Take(numberOfBananas)` and `subBananas.Skip(numberOfBananas)`? Why call `Cast<XmlNode>()` on a value already of type `IQueryable<XmlNode>` or `IEnumerable<XmlNode>`? It looks like the code is much more complex than it needs to be. See my answer for what I believe to be a simpler approach.

Comment: @DaisyShipton in the naive case the OP gave it doesn't matter.  If he's streaming a large XDoc and doesn't want to load everything into memory using IEnumerable, it does.  Good answer as well.

Comment: The OP is loading the doc into an `XmlNodeList`. How do you expect `AsQueryable` to help with that? Even if we take out that aspect and assume a lazily-loaded `IEnumerable<T>`, using `Skip` and `Take` wouldn't cause the whole sequence to be loaded into memory at once, and using `AsQueryable` wouldn't remove the repeated skipping/taking. I just don't see any benefit here.